# Usage of Jtextarea in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I have a JTABLE with three columns. First column is textfield, the Second and third is JTextarea.. Using tab key I can navigate from one cell to another. While navigating from Jtextfield column to JTextarea column , The JTextarea is not highlighted, how to set a color for JTextarea when it get focused  , so I can easily find which column has the focus.. How I will set that color.?
Please give some suggestions..

Thanks in Advance 
Vishwa

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Are the textareas renderers or editors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Color` object and invoke the `setBackground(Color)` method on your JTextArea, after checking if it has focus using the `hasFocus()`.

For example:

```
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        Color c = Color.CYAN;

        if(area.hasFocus())
        {
            area.setBackground(c);
        }
```

Don't forget to save the original color of the (accessible by calling `area.getBackground()`) before you change it, and to set it back to this when it loses focus.